# Why a softer phonon is easier to get excited

Tags: solid-state-physics

In Kittel's book, "Some other structure B may have a softer or lower frequency phonon spectrum than A. As the temperature is increased the phonons in B will be
more highly excited (higher thermal average occupancies) than the phonons in
A."

Can you let me know why softer phonon is easier to get excited? Is it just because it has lower $hf$? Or it is due to other reasons? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Phonons with low energy are called "soft" for this reason. It means the same.

Comment: It is like a softer spring in a harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Yep, soft=low energy,  and hard=high energy.